# Nightwatch - Do another action if the element is not present

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nightwatch.js

How to write a simple if/else in NightwatchJS? If element is present, click this element, else - click another element.

```
'Test2: click login button': function(client) {

    client.expect.element('.login .btn').to.be.present;
    client.click('.login .btn');


//  if "client.expect.element('.login .btn') is not present(visible)" - 
//      but "client.expect.element('a.menu-link').to.be.present(visible)";
//  client.click('a.menu-link');


    client.pause(1000);
});
```

},

Answer (score 2):

There may be more than one way to do this, but I'd use the [Webdriver Protocol](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#protocol)'s [`.element()`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/element.html) function:

```
'Test2: click login button': client => {
  const buttonSelector = '.login .btn';
  const menuLinkSelector = 'a.menu-link';
  client.element('css selector', buttonSelector, result => {
    if (result.status > -1) {
      // `.login .btn` is present
      client.click(buttonSelector);
    } else {
      // else, check for `a.menu-link`
      client.element('css selector', menuLinkSelector, () => {
        client.click(menuLinkSelector);
      });
    }   
  });
  client.end();
}
```